# jQuery ajax async 'true' gets my web-app stuck until the data is returned

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am working on a PHP based web app (that i didn't build).

I am running this ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/potato/ajax.php?module=test_module",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    data: {
            start_ts: that.start_date,
            stop_ts: that.end_date, 
            submitted: true
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
        console.log('Start: ' + new Date().toLocaleString());
        // Show Chart Loading 
        that.qwChart.showLoading({ 
            color: '#00b0f0', 
            // text: that.returnNumWithPrecent(that.progress)
            text: that.qwChartProgress
        });

        // If data div isn't displayed
        if (!that.dataDisplayed) {
            // Show divs loading
            that.showMainDiv();
        } else {
            that.$qwTbody.slideUp('fast');
            that.$qwTbody.html('');
        }
    },
    complete: function(){},
    success: function(result){
        console.log('End: ' + new Date().toLocaleString());

        // Clear timer
        clearInterval(timer);

        // Set progressbar to 100%
        that.setProgressBarTo100();

        // Show Download Button
        that.downloadBtn.style.display = 'inline-block';

        // Insert Chart Data
        that.insertChartData(result);

        // Insert Table Data
        that.insertTableData(result);
    }
});
```

And for some reason it gets my whole web-app stuck until it returns the data. I know that [by default ajax requests are set to 'true'](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) but i added it anyway just to make sure it is. 
If it is async, it should do the job without getting my web-app stuck, am I right? What can be the problem? Is this a serverside problem? How do I debug this situation?

Edit: By saying "stuck" I mean - when I wait for the response after submitting the ajax call, refreshing the page or opening in parallel other pages (within my web app only) display a white loading screen. Whenever the ajax call returns the data - the white page loads to the requested page.

Data is returned from the PHP file:

```
<?php 
require_once("/www/common/api/db.php");

    if (!empty($_POST['submitted'])) {

    // error_reporting(-1);
    // Users Array:
    $users      = get_qw_data($start_ts_to_date, $stop_ts_to_date);

    // Summary Array:
    $summary    = get_qw_summary($users);

    // QW Score Array:
    $qws        = get_qw_score($users);

    // Generate CSV Report files
    /* Remove old:*/ 
    if (!is_file_dir_exist($customer))
        create_qw_directory($customer);

    /* Report #1: */ users_apps_google_macros_ma($users['users'], $customer);
    /* Report #2: */ usage_and_qw_summary($summary, $customer);
    /* Report #3: */ qw_score($qws, $customer);
    /* Zip Files: */ zip_qw_files($customer);

    echo json_encode($qws);
}
```

Comment: Can you give more information that 'stuck'. What exactly happens? Or doesn't happen if it appears to be stuck. Is the entire browser locked while the request happens? How much data is returned from the request?

Comment: Try commenting out everything inside `beforeSend`, does it change anything? Perhaps `qwChart. showLoading` is causing the block?

Comment: _How_ is it stuck? Is anything “blocking” regarding the UI/Frontend; are other requests “pending” until this one is finished; ...? Are you using PHP sessions? Those are a prime candidate for other requests getting “stuck”, because the session file gets write-locked, so as long as one running script instance has the session open, all others have to wait. (Solution to that would be to call session_write_close as soon as possible.)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I edited my post, if it's still not clear please update my and i will try to explain better.

Comment: That behaviour sounds like your server is restricting the number of connections and/or requests coming from your IP. Are you running on a remote server or a local one?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this is happening both in my local dev environment and on production.

Comment: @mulquin I tried that and this didn't solve the problem...

Comment: @CBroe Yes i am using sessions (logged in users have sessions stored for validation ect')

Comment: remove before send and success function and check where it is still blocking your app. because sometimes due to heavy UI operations App becomes unresponsive.

Comment: @sirajpathan nope. didn't work.

Comment: I think the problem may be in the code that performs the loading of pages, etc

Comment: Alternatively, does this occur in all browsers?

Comment: Have you tried closing the session as soon as possible in your script that processes this AJAX request?

Comment: @CBroe SOLVED! I added `session_write_close();` right after `require_once("/www/common/api/db.php");` and everything works in parallel to the ajax call. I don't really understand why this is happening and how did `session_write_close` solved it. To request the file `url: "/potato/ajax.php?module=test_module",` via ajax I DO NEED the session (without it: the web-app cant validate me as a loggedin user). So i basically just break the session? so how other things work in parallel now that depend onit?How exactly is it locked?When running something in ajax - it locks the session? for what reason?

Comment: @CBroe Can you write me an answer explaining exactly what happens behind the seance? How exactly the session is working in regard to my case?

Comment: Added an answer with an extended explanation for you ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP sessions are a prime candidate for other requests getting “stuck”, because the session file gets write-locked, so as long as one running script instance has the session open, all others have to wait.

Solution to that is to call `session_write_close` as soon as possible.

---

A little extended explanation:

The default storage mechanism for session data is simply the file system. For every active session, PHP simply puts a file into the configured session directory, and writes the contents of $_SESSION to it, so that it can be read back from there on the next request that needs to access it.

Now if several PHP script instances tried to write changed session data to that file “simultaneously”, that would quite obviously have great conflict/error potential.

Therefor PHP puts a write lock on the session file, as soon as one script instance accesses the session - everybody else, other requests (to the same script, or a different one also using the session), will have to wait, until the first script is done with the session, and the write lock gets released again.

Per default, that happens when the script is done running. But if you have longer running scripts, this can easily lead to such “blocking” effects as you are experiencing here. The solution to that is to explicitly tell PHP (via `session_write_close`), “I’m done with the session here, not gonna write any new/changed data to it from this point on - so feel free to release the lock, so that the next script can start reading the session data.”

The important thing is that you only do this after your script is done manipulating any session data. You can still *read* from $_SESSION during the rest of the script - but you can not write to it any more. (So anything like `$_SESSION['foo'] = 'bar';` would have to fail, after you released the session.)

If the only purpose the session serves at this point (in this specific script) is to check user authentication, then you can close the session directly after that. The rest of the script can then run as long as it wants to, without blocking other scripts from accessing the same session any more.

---

This isn’t limited to AJAX requests - those are just one of the places where you usually notice stuff like this first, because otherwise you usually don’t have that many requests using the session running in “parallel”. But if you were to f.e. open a long-running script multiple times in several browser tabs, you would notice the same effect there - in the first tab the script will run and do its business, whereas in the following tabs you should notice that those requests are “hanging” as well, as long as the previous script instance holds the write lock on the session.

Comment: `as soon as one script instance accesses the session - everybody else, other requests (to the same script, or a different one also using the session), will have to wait, until the first script is done with the session, and the write lock gets released again.` - so if i run the script, and an other user (different session) trying to communicate with that file, he will have to wait for my script to end?

Comment: @RickSanchez, no, this is limited to the same session. A different user has a different session ID, and therefor also a different file in which their session info is stored. Each session has its own data file.