# jQuery $.get() is blocking other requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http, request

I'm developing a web application and use jQuery to make asynchronous HTTP requests to my API. I have a detail view where you can see a lot of information of a specific object stored in the database. Because there is a lot of information and data that is linked to other objects, I make different calls to my API to gather different information for my views.

In the 'detail view' I have some kind of widgets that show the requested information. For that, I make about 5-7 HTTP GET requests to my API. When using the debugger (both Safari and Firefox), I can see that some requests are blocking other requests and the page takes a lot of time until everything is loaded and shown to the user.

I make a request like this:

```
$.get("api/api.php?object=myobject&endpoint=someendpoint", function(data) {
    // data is JSON formatted
    $("#my-widget input").val(data["name"]);
});
```

And another one e.g. like this:

```
$.get("api/api.php?object=anotherobject&endpoint=anotherendpoint", function(data) {
    // data is JSON formatted
    $("#other-widget input").val(data["somekey"]);
});
```

If the first request takes a little longer to finish, it blocks the second request until the callback function of the first request finished. But why? I thought that those calls are asynchronous and non-blocking.

I want to build a fast web application for a company where the requests are **only** made inside the local network, so a request should only take about 10-50ms (or even less). But the page takes about 10 seconds to show up with all information.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a JavaScript framework that can be used for exactly this problem? Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: As you can see in the screenshot, the requests have to wait some seconds, and if the request is fired, it takes a few seconds until a response comes back.

If I call the URL directly in my browser or do a GET request using `curl` it is a lot faster.

[image: Screenshot of timeline]

EDIT2: Thanks @CBroe! The session file write lock was the problem. As long as the session file is locked, no other script can run until the previous script finished. I just called `session_write_close()` immediately after `session_start()` and it runs a lot faster now.

**Attention:** Use `session_write_close()` only if you don't need to write to the `$_SESSION` array. Reading is possible after that, but writing not. (See this topic for further details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50368260/1427878)

Comment: could you check your network tab?

Comment: How does it block the second request? Is it possible that your server only handle one request at a time so that the second one needs to wait for the response of the first request?

Comment: Make sure that jQuery is set to make async calls - see here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Comment: most browsers allow about 6 active requests at a time.

Comment: @Axnyff how can I check that?

Comment: @PeterB thanks - but the documentation says that async default value is set to `true`. I didn't change that.

Comment: @DanielA.White what do you mean? That is the network tab of my Safari developer tools.

Comment: Most often the PHP session file write lock causes issues like this; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50368260/1427878 for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: @beeef Look when the second request starts: if it start directly but is stalled until the end of the first request, it's probably linked to your backend. You should use the network tabs of the developer tools of your browser to check that

Comment: @beeef true, but you need to make sure. There could be code that you are not seeing, which is doing things that you are not expecting. The setting can be changed globally for all future calls. It might be worth a try to use the extended call syntax `$.ajax()` and specifying `async: true` explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll try that out.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for your answer! That was the problem, it works like a charm now. The page shows up in about 1 second, before it was about 12 seconds.

Comment: @beeef What DanielAWhite means is that most browsers have an upper limit on how many Ajax requests to a given host can be active at a time, generally from 6-10ish.