# AJAX calls to the same page are not ASYNC

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I faced this issue while coding http requests: The requests to the same page on http://142.93.47.235 host (which is LAMP) are not async.

Here's what I mean:

The server side has 3 files: index.php, pindex.php and hindex.php. Their content is exactly the same for all of them:

```
<?php
    $a = Date('H:i:s d, m, Y');
    set_time_limit(0);
    sleep(rand(1,10));
    $b = Date('H:i:s d, m, Y');
    exit($a." ".$b);
```

So I try to make xhr to this pages (or only one of them 3 times - that works the same way) in a loop.

```
    var index = ["/","/pindex.php","hindex.php"];

    for (var i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {

        var url = "http://142.93.47.235";

        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("GET", url, true);
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && request.status === 200) {
                console.log(this.responseText);
            }
        };
        request.send();
    }
```

I were expecting these requests to answer asynchronously, that's why I said php to sleep for random time and echo start time and finish time of a request, so I can get the exact one that returned first.

This way, for example, if the hindex.php file generates 3 second sleep and index.php generated 10 seconds, the hindex will answer first. But, instead every time all that 3 requests go one by one no matter what sleep time is less or more.

Comment: Do you use sessions? If there is a running script with a sessions all other php scripts with the same sessions have to wait. You can prevent the session blocking with `session_write_close();`

Comment: @RolandStarke Thank you for your answer! I used session_write_close(); and it worked!! You're the pro!

Comment: A little more in-depth explanation of the issue in my answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/50368260/1427878

Comment: @CBroe Nice explanation; I'd say anyone reading this question in future should see that answer, so I've marked this as duplicate.